woocommerce send to line oa
i writing script for order notification to line oa but I not work
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: WooCommerce LINE Notification
*/

// Add a menu page to WordPress Admin Dashboard
add_action('admin_menu', 'woocommerce_line_notification_menu');

function woocommerce_line_notification_menu() {
    add_submenu_page(
        'woocommerce', // Parent menu slug (if you want to add it under WooCommerce menu)
        'LINE Notification Settings', // Page title
        'LINE Notification', // Menu title
        'manage_options', // Capability required to access the page
        'woocommerce-line-notification-settings', // Menu slug
        'woocommerce_line_notification_settings_page' // Callback function to render the page content
    );
}

// Callback function to render settings page
function woocommerce_line_notification_settings_page() {
    // Check user capabilities
    if (!current_user_can('manage_options')) {
        return;
    }
    
    // Output HTML for settings page
    ?>
    <div class="wrap">
        <h1><?php echo esc_html(get_admin_page_title()); ?></h1>
        <form action="options.php" method="post">
            <?php
            // Output security fields for the registered setting "woocommerce_line_notification_options"
            settings_fields('woocommerce_line_notification_options');
            // Output setting sections and their fields
            do_settings_sections('woocommerce_line_notification');
            // Output submit button
            submit_button('Save Settings');
            ?>
        </form>
        <form>
            <button id="woocommerce-line-notification-test-button" class="button button-primary">Test Notification</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <?php
}

// Add a button for testing LINE Notification
add_action('admin_init', 'woocommerce_line_notification_add_test_button');

function woocommerce_line_notification_add_test_button() {
    add_action('admin_footer', 'woocommerce_line_notification_test_button_script');
}

function woocommerce_line_notification_test_button_script() {
    ?>
    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            $('#woocommerce-line-notification-test-button').click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var access_token = $('#woocommerce_line_notification_access_token').val(); // Get LINE Channel Access Token from input field
                var message = 'This is a test message from your WordPress website.';
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'https://api.line.me/v2/bot/message/push',
                    type: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token
                    },
                    data: JSON.stringify({
                        to: '2004672095', // User ID or Group ID
                        messages: [{
                            type: 'text',
                            text: message
                        }]
                    }),
                    success: function(response) {
                        alert('Test notification sent successfully!');
                    },
                    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                        alert('Error occurred while sending test notification. Please check your LINE Channel Access Token.');
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
    <?php
}

// Register settings
add_action('admin_init', 'woocommerce_line_notification_register_settings');

function woocommerce_line_notification_register_settings() {
    // Register a new setting for "woocommerce_line_notification" section
    register_setting('woocommerce_line_notification_options', 'woocommerce_line_notification_access_token');
    
    // Add a new section to the "woocommerce_line_notification" settings page
    add_settings_section(
        'woocommerce_line_notification_settings_section',
        'LINE Notification Settings',
        'woocommerce_line_notification_settings_section_callback',
        'woocommerce_line_notification'
    );
    
    // Add a new field to the "woocommerce_line_notification" section
    add_settings_field(
        'woocommerce_line_notification_access_token',
        'LINE Channel Access Token',
        'woocommerce_line_notification_access_token_callback',
        'woocommerce_line_notification',
        'woocommerce_line_notification_settings_section'
    );
}

// Callback function for section description
function woocommerce_line_notification_settings_section_callback() {
    echo 'Enter your LINE Channel Access Token below:';
}

// Callback function for access token field
function woocommerce_line_notification_access_token_callback() {
    $access_token = get_option('woocommerce_line_notification_access_token');
    echo '<input type="text" id="woocommerce_line_notification_access_token" name="woocommerce_line_notification_access_token" value="' . esc_attr($access_token) . '" />';
}

// Hook into WooCommerce New Order
add_action('woocommerce_new_order', 'send_line_notification', 10, 1);

function send_line_notification($order_id) {
    $order = wc_get_order($order_id);
    
    // Get necessary information from the order
    $order_number = $order->get_order_number();
    $order_total = $order->get_total();
    $billing_first_name = $order->get_billing_first_name();
    $billing_last_name = $order->get_billing_last_name();
    
    // Compose message
    $message = "New order received!\n";
    $message .= "Order Number: $order_number\n";
    $message .= "Customer Name: $billing_first_name $billing_last_name\n";
    $message .= "Total: $order_total\n";
    
    // Get LINE Channel Access Token
    $access_token = get_option('woocommerce_line_notification_access_token');
    
    // LINE API endpoint
    $api_url = 'https://api.line.me/v2/bot/message/push';
    
    // Headers
    $headers = array(
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Authorization: Bearer ' . $access_token,
    );
    
    // Data to be sent
    $data = array(
        'to' => '2004672095', // User ID or Group ID
        'messages' => array(
            array(
                'type' => 'text',
                'text' => $message,
            ),
        ),
    );
    
    // Encode data
    $data_string = json_encode($data);
    
    // Initialize cURL
    $ch = curl_init($api_url);
    
    // Set the cURL options
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    
    // Execute cURL
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    
    // Check for errors
    if (curl_errno($ch)) {
        error_log('Error occurred: ' . curl_error($ch));
    }
    
    // Close cURL
    curl_close($ch);
}
?>

but I am not working help me please I put my
LINE Channel Access Token and test it still did not work I don't know it what wrong my script or token it is line oa Messaging API in line develop I have no idea how to fix this
I tried to use Channel secret,channel Id but not work too

"It looks like your code is set up correctly to send notifications. If it works with the test button but not with actual orders, you might want to check a few things:
Ensure that the woocommerce_new_order action is firing. Sometimes, if payment gateways use custom order status transitions, it might not trigger as expected.
Check your server logs for any errors that might be occurring during the actual order notification process which might not be happening in the test scenario.

Confirm that the order_id passed to the send_line_notification function is valid and that the wc_get_order function is returning a proper order object.
Consider adding logging right inside your send_line_notification function to see if all the variables are being set as expected and the function is being reached.
If the issue persists, you might want to share relevant parts of your server error log to diagnose any silent failures."
